# Issue with Sql update - The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql

I have the following query but not sure why getting the following error below:

```
    CREATE TABLE #TBL (building varchar(256), oldloc int, newloc int);

    BULK INSERT #TBL FROM 'C:\Folder\file.csv' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',');
    Update data_Adj 
    set data_Adj.LocID = #TBL.newloc
    where data_Adj.LocID = #TBL.oldloc and data_Adj.Building = #TBL.building
```

getting the following error:

The multi-part identifier "#TBL.oldloc" could not be bound.

The multi-part identifier "#TBL.building" could not be bound.

Comment: #TBL is not part of the UPDATE statement.  Suggest going to the UPDATE documentation for your platform -- which is SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `from` clause to reference `#tbl`:

```
Update a 
    set LocID = t.newloc
    from data_adj a join
         #tbl t
         on a.LocID = t.oldloc and a.Building = t.building;
```